# Interprocess Communication over Network in C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, ipc

I'm using C++ to develop the server side of a game which multiple servers need to communicate with each other using Publisher/Subscriber pattern. Each server subscribes to some events on different servers. All servers are located on the same network so latency and packet-loss should be very low. The inter-server communication should be as efficient as possible since many events happen each second.

Are there any libraries out there i can use for this purpose?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What is your OS and compiler?

Comment: The server is Linux based and we used gcc to compile it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to combine [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) (for async sockets I/O) with [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/signals.html) (for Observer pattern) or [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/signals2.html) (threadsafe version of Boost.Signals) to achieve what you want.

There is a simple example showing how this might work [here](http://dancinghacker.com/code/dataflow/dataflow/signals/introduction/examples/distributed.html).  Note that this uses a wrapper on Boost.Signal, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially talking about a socket library.  That's different from IPC, which refers to Interprocess Communication between two or more processes on the *same* computer - as opposed to over a network.  Network communication requires socket programming, so you probably want a good, high-performance socket library.  [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a very good C++ portable socket library which provides both TCP and UDP sockets.

Comment: In fact, IPC can mean both: communication of multiple processes on the same computer or one multiple computers, connected via network. Nevertheless, TCP/IP sockets are the tool of choice for that.